# How to create a color picker (palette) with limited options?

Tags: javascript, xpages

I want to use a color picker on my XPage with limited options. So far I found out that I can create a color picker with this code:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" type="color"></xp:inputText>
```

Yet I want to have an input field with only limited color options (6-10). Is there any XPage control which offers this?

Comment: There is no XPage control that offers this out of the box. So you should continue your investigation into `type="color"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create an inputText with `type="color"`. Additionally, I added some default colors:

```
var optionList = ["#ffffff", "#FFBC00"];

function fillDataList() {
    var container = document.getElementById("#{id:colorPicker}"),
    i = 0,
    len = optionList.length,
    dl = document.createElement('datalist');
    container.setAttribute('list','dlColors'); 
    dl.id = 'dlColors';
    for (; i < len; i += 1) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = optionList[i];
        dl.appendChild(option);
    }
    container.appendChild(dl);
}
fillDataList();
```